# SkiaSharp Calc new point coordinates after applying 3d rotation

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I am using a matrix to translate then rotate in 3d (x, y, z) using the `xRotate`, `yRotate`, `zRotate`, `depth == 300` vars.

```cs
using (var bmp = new SKBitmap(800, 600))
using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(bmp))
using (var paint = new SKPaint())
{
    canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
    paint.IsAntialias = true;

    // Find center of canvas
    var info = bmp.Info;
    float xCenter = info.Width / 2;
    float yCenter = info.Height / 2;

    // Translate center to origin
    SKMatrix matrix = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(-xCenter, -yCenter);
    // Use 3D matrix for 3D rotations and perspective
    SKMatrix44 matrix44 = SKMatrix44.CreateIdentity();
    matrix44.PostConcat(SKMatrix44.CreateRotationDegrees(1, 0, 0, xRotate));
    matrix44.PostConcat(SKMatrix44.CreateRotationDegrees(0, 1, 0, yRotate));
    matrix44.PostConcat(SKMatrix44.CreateRotationDegrees(0, 0, 1, zRotate));

    SKMatrix44 perspectiveMatrix = SKMatrix44.CreateIdentity();
    perspectiveMatrix[3, 2] = -1 / depth;
    matrix44.PostConcat(perspectiveMatrix);

    // Concatenate with 2D matrix
    SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref matrix, matrix44.Matrix);

    // Translate back to center
    SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref matrix,
        SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(xCenter, yCenter));

    // Set the matrix and display the bitmap
    canvas.SetMatrix(matrix);
    canvas.DrawBitmap(currentImage, 50, 25, paint);

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp.ToBitmap();
}
```

If I have some `Point` in the original `currentImage`, I want to calculate its new location after drawing the transformed image. How can I do that? Would I reuse the matrix to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Let the point be (1, 2) in the `currentImage`. Then simply:

```
var newPoint = matrix.MapPoint(1, 2);
newPoint =new SkPoint(50 + newPoint.X, 25 + newPoint.Y);  // + offsets of DrawImage
```

Or to draw on a canvas that already mapped using `canvas.SetMatrix`

```
var newPoint = new SKPoint(1, 2);
canvas.DrawCircle(newPoint.X + 50, newPoint.Y + 25, 7, paint); // + offsets of DrawImage
```